# Is it possible to produce Fuel Efficiency graph using OBD2 app

Tags: obd-ii, efficiency

Can [the Torque app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.prowl.torque&hl=en_GB) be used to produce a [Fuel Efficiency](https://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mpgforspeed.com%2Ffegov_graph.gif&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mpgforspeed.com%2F&docid=i-x_uDg97cQgrM&tbnid=NfoGut7cFtT6SM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiB4_unpMLWAhVSKVAKHZzSCi8QMwhEKAAwAA..i&w=233&h=182&safe=off&bih=834&biw=1440&q=fuel%20efficiency%20graph&ved=0ahUKEwiB4_unpMLWAhVSKVAKHZzSCi8QMwhEKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8) graph for my car, or do I need a specialist for this kind of information ?

Generally I want to measure the most fuel efficient extra-urban speed.

Comment: Historical or live?

Comment: @SolarMike Live.